# How to get the file/files containing PATH environment variables?

Tags: php, macos, path, terminal, homebrew

I have used echo $PATH to get all my path environment variables.

But how do i get the file containing the path declaration?

I cant find a .bashrc_profile and n .profile i only see

```
    PATH="$(brew --prefix josegonzalez/php/php54)/bin:$PATH
```

I'm trying to replace my php PATH variable from /usr/local/opt/php54/bin. to the latest 5.5.
Im still downloading using this site's instruction http://php-osx.liip.ch/, because when using brew install php55 using this instructions https://lastzero.net/2013/08/howto-install-php-5-5-and-phpunit-on-os-x-via-homebrew/ , it gives me an error

```
    Error: SHA1 mismatch
    Expected: 3952e6d678164a700296dbdb8e506b8bb80727fb
    Actual: e5fee0b2c74dae5a50042c5f664909c9ee7c6224
    Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/php55-5.5.3
    (To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)
```

I tried removing the file above, alot of times using rm. It can be removed, then checked if the folder is gone, but when i use

```
    brew install php55
```

again, it gives the same error again. It autogenerates then ives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

The global bashrc file is located in /private/etc/bashrc in osx 10.9. This file (at least on my computer) does not contain a $PATH variable, however, one could be added and then modified to fit your specifications.

It is worth noting that even though the .bashrc_profile does not exit in ~/, creating one may allow you to define the $PATH as well.

I hope this helps, comment if anything is unclear.